# If File Directory is Empty C#

Tags: c#, file, if-statement, directory

So I'm building a console app that has a feature to list all files in a directory and I would like to tell it to display a message "Directory is empty" if there are no files in that folder.  My code is returning the folder contents properly but I can't get it to display my text message if the directory is empty, it's like it's ignoring the if statement.  Anybody have suggestions as to why it's not working?  Thanks!

```
        Console.WriteLine(" Displaying Contents of Write Directory: ");
        Console.WriteLine(" ---------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine();

        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(writeDir);
        for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" Directory is Empty!");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                string path = filePaths[i];
                Console.WriteLine("File: " + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path));
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it won't reach your `if` when there are no files:

```
if ( filePaths.Length > 0 )
{
   for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; ++i)
   {
      string path = filePaths[i];
      Console.WriteLine("File: " + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path));
      Console.WriteLine();
   }
 }
 else{
   Console.WriteLine();
   Console.WriteLine(" Directory is Empty!");
   Console.WriteLine();
   Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(writeDir);
if (filePaths.Length == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(" Directory is Empty!");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; ++i)
    {
        string path = filePaths[i];
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your if statement checking the size of the array out of the for-loop.
Your for-loop's conditions are such that it won't trigger unless `file.Paths.Length` returns a number greater 0, so when there are no files in the directory, the if statement isn't being checked.